# Como puedo inhabilitar la etiqueta input type “text” por un checkbox

Tags: html5, bootstrap

trabajo en un proyecto y quiero que al habilitar el `checkbox` se me inhabilite la entrada de texto de tal manera que el usuario no pueda ingresar datos en el. Tampoco he podido reducir el tamaño del `input type="text"` ya que ocupa la página de lado a lado. El cambio debo hacerlo vía `HTML` y trabajamos con `Bootstrap`. Gracias!.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class = "checkbox-control">
        <input aplicacion="2" cliente="Empresa.Cliente" cols="100" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo es obligatorio." id="PassIlimitada" name="PassIlimitada" ngmodelparent="configuracion" ng_model="configuracion.PassIlimitada" placeholder="Contraseña" rows="5" type="checkbox" value="true" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"><input name="PassIlimitada" type="hidden" value="false">
    </div>
</div>
<p><b>Días vencimiento de la contraseña</b></p>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="configuracion.Minutos" placeholder="Días" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `jQuery` puedes lograr que el `input` se active/inactive tal como lo necesitas.

Para controlar el tamaño del `input`, puedes usar `CSS`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#check").click(function() {  
        if($("#check").is(':checked')) {  
             $("#dias").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {  
            $("#dias").attr("disabled", false); 
        }  
    }); 
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#vencimiento {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#dias {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12">
    <div class = "checkbox-control">
        <input id="check" aplicacion="2" cliente="Empresa.Cliente" cols="100" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo es obligatorio." id="PassIlimitada" name="PassIlimitada" ngmodelparent="configuracion" ng_model="configuracion.PassIlimitada" placeholder="Contraseña" rows="5" type="checkbox" value="true" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        <input name="PassIlimitada" type="" value="false">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12">
    <label id="vencimiento">Días vencimiento de la contraseña</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dias" ng-model="configuracion.Minutos" placeholder="Días" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me encanta esta solución, pero internamente tengo un problema para ejecutarla. Tal vez tengas una idea de hacerlo en el HTML unicamente?
Muchas gracias !

Comment: @NicoFlorez El tamaño, si... con estilos en línea que no es muy recomendable pero es válido: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dias" ng-model="configuracion.Minutos" placeholder="Días" style="width: 50%;">`. Para activar/desactivar... veo que usas directivas de `AngularJS`... No conozco mucho del tema pero tal vez [esta información](http://www.cursoangularjs.es/doku.php?id=unidades:02_angular:05_ngdisabled) pueda ayudarte un poco, allí veo un ejemplo con lo que necesitas. Perdón por no poder ayudarte más, pero mi escaso conocimiento aún no llega tan lejos.

Comment: Excelente ! me sirvió bastante ...
Muchas Gracias !